# How to logout user(not current) by login?

Tags: java, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security

I have 2 roles in my system: **user** and **admin**

**admin** can logout any **user** by name.

How can I do this?
I need something like this:

`service.logoutUser(anotherUserName)`

config looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers
                 ....
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/api/login")
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .and()
            .rememberMe()
                .key("...")
                .rememberMeCookieName("...")
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and()
            .logout()
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler())
                .permitAll();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
...
...
Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
userRoles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
User user = new User(anotherUserName, "", userRoles);
List<SessionInformation> sessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(u, false);

for(SessionInformation info : infos) {
   info.expireNow();
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify why do you use empty string instead of password?

Comment: You do not need the password for what you are trying to do. Additionally your code must never need to know a user password. A password must only be written by the user and encrypted.

Comment: API looks is not natural)

Comment: Where can I found user roles by name?